# "Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'LeaderBoard' in field list" in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I began getting the error:

Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'LeaderBoard' in field list

after I implemented the following trigger:

```
USE `broadside`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `LeaderBoard_AINS` 
AFTER INSERT ON `LeaderBoard` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if ((broadside.LeaderBoard.username= NEW.username) AND (broadside.LeaderBoard.userscore< NEW.userscore))
    then
        DELETE FROM `broadside`.`LeaderBoard`
        WHERE (username = NEW.username AND userscore != NEW.userscore);
    end if;
    if (broadside.LeaderBoard.username= NEW.username AND broadside.LeaderBoard.userscore< NEW.userscore)
    then
        DELETE FROM `broadside`.`LeaderBoard`
        WHERE (username = NEW.username AND userscore != NEW.userscore);
    end if;
end
```

The table name is LeaderBoard and the database name is broadside. It compiled fine, but when i try inserting an element and the trigger actually gets triggered I get the 1109 error shown above. Can someone please help?

Comment: If the table name is really upper/lower case then you must back-quote it _everywhere_ you use it.  There are a couple of places where it's quoted and some where it's not.

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition, remove referring the table and compare values directly.

**Change**

```
IF (
    ( broadside.LeaderBoard.username = NEW.username )
    AND
    ( broadside.LeaderBoard.userscore < NEW.userscore )
) THEN
```

**To**:

```
IF (
    ( username = NEW.username ) AND ( userscore < NEW.userscore )
) THEN
```

BTW: why do you need the second if condition?

***Refer to***: a similar posting on MySQL Forum
[**MySQL Forums :: Triggers :: #1109 - Unknown table 'xyz' in field list**](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,372953,372953)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like:

```sql
...
IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM `leaderboard` WHERE `username` = NEW.`username` AND `userscore` < NEW.`userscore`) THEN
...
```

However, then you have an error like the following:

```sql
Error Code : 1442
Can't update table 'leaderboard' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

when trying to execute the `DELETE`, cause:

> [B.5. MySQL 5.6 FAQ: Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-triggers.html) : [B.5.9: Can triggers access tables?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9)
>
> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger
>   can also affect other tables, but it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.